# How can I connect my iphone with ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, connection, iphone

Cannot connect Iphone 5 ios7 to ubuntu 12.04

1. Endless loop of 'Trust this computer' if I trust it.
2. The device 'Samis' is locked. Enter the passcode on the device and click 'Try again'.
3. Unable to mount device with message

   DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)

**How can I connect my iphone with ubuntu?**

Comment: This is a known issue between ios7 and Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1207812

Comment: Here's a solution that worked for me for iPhone 5s running iOS 7: https://gist.github.com/keyvanfatehi/8922430

Comment: Ignore that.  That link is for raspian.

Comment: Recently [KDE Connect](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/kde-connect/id1580245991) was added to Apple Store